# 'Class Instance Object' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope, header-files

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm really struggling with trying to define a single instance of a class `ConflictGraph` and access its methods from different methods inside another class `ConvexHullBuilder`.

For problem's reasons, I need to initialize `ConflictGraph` on a certain point in `ConvexHullBuilder::computeConvexHull()`, when I have some vertices and a `dcel`, then, I need to call `ConflictGraph's initialize()` to properly initialize the ConflictGraph. This works fine.

The problem occurs when I try to call ConflictGraph's `lookForVisibleFaces()` inside `ConvexHullBuilder::finalizeConvexHull`.

I get the following error

> error: ‘conflictGraph’ was not declared in this scope
>
> facesVisible = conflictGraph.lookForVisibleFaces(remainingVertices[i]);
>
> ```
>                  ^
> ```

The types are a bit tricky but don't pay attention to them. I just need an insight on how to access external class methods inside inner class methods

**ConflictGraph.h**:

```
class ConflictGraph{
public:
    ConflictGraph(DrawableDcel* dcel, std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> vertices);
    void initializeConflictGraph();
    std::set<Dcel::Face*>* lookForVisibleFaces(Dcel::Vertex*);
private:
    DrawableDcel *dcel;
    std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> tetrahedronVertices;

    void checkVisibility();

}
```

**ConflictGraph.cpp**:

```
#include "conflictgraph.h"

/**
 * @brief ConflictGraph::ConflictGraph() Constructor
 * @params takes dcel and tetrahedron vertices as input
 */
ConflictGraph::ConflictGraph(DrawableDcel* dcel, std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*> tetrahedronVertices){
    this->dcel = dcel;
    this->tetrahedronVertices = tetrahedronVertices;
}

/**
 * @brief ConflictGraph::initializeConflictGraph() initializes the conflict graph
 */
void ConflictGraph::initializeConflictGraph(){
    //Check which faces see which vertices and viceversa
    checkVisibility();//Works
}

/**
 * @brief lookForVisibleFaces(Dcel::Vertex* vertex) finds which faces are visible from a given vertex
 * @param VERTEX vertex given vertex
 * @retuns map of visible faces and passed Vertex
 */
std::set<FACE>* ConflictGraph::lookForVisibleFaces(Dcel::Vertex* vertex){
 . . .
}
```

**ConvexHullBuilder.h**:

```
#include "conflictgraph.h"

class ConvexHullBuilder{

public:
    ConvexHullBuilder(DrawableDcel* dcel);
    void computeConvexHull();

private:
    DrawableDcel *dcel;
    void finalizeConvexHull(std::vector<Dcel::Vertex*);
};
```

**ConvexHullBuilder.cpp**

```
#include "convexhullbuilder.h"

/**
 * @brief ConvexHullBuilder::ConvexHullBuilder() Conmstructor
 * @params takes dcel as input
 */
ConvexHullBuilder::ConvexHullBuilder(DrawableDcel* dcel){
   this->dcel = dcel;
}

/**
 * @brief ConvexHullBuilder::computeConvexHull() takes dcel as input.
 *        Starts the algorithm calling all the different functions needed.
 *        Adds Vertices, Builds a Tetrahedron . . .
 */
void ConvexHullBuilder::computeConvexHull(){
. . .
/** VerticesForCG is an array of pointers to vertex, properly filled
    allVertices contains all the remaining vertices**/
//Initializes Conflict Graph with Dcel And First 4 Vertices
    ConflictGraph conflictGraph = ConflictGraph(dcel, verticesForCG);
    conflictGraph.initializeConflictGraph(); //Works

    //Loop through remaining vertices
    finalizeConvexHull(allVertices);//Does not Work

}

/**
 * @brief ConvexHullBuilder::finalizeConvexHull starts last phase to build the convex hull
 * @param VERTEX_POINTERS_LIST remainingVertices i=4 -> n vertices
 */
void ConvexHullBuilder::finalizeConvexHull(std::vector<Dcel::Vertex* remainingVertices){

    //Loop through remaining vertices
    for(unsigned int i=4; i<remainingVertices.size(); i++){

       //Initializing faces visible by a vertex
       std::set<Dcel::Face*>* facesVisible;

      //Check Which faces sees i-Vertex and assigning them
      facesVisible = conflictGraph.lookForVisibleFaces(remainingVertices[i]);//Error

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I also tried passing `ConflictGraph` instance into `ConvexHullBuilder.h` like

```
private:
    DrawableDcel *dcel;
    ConflictGraph *conflictGraph;
```

And in `ConvexHullBuilder.cpp`:

```
{
  //Initializes Conflict Graph with Dcel And First 4 Vertices
  this->conflictGraph = new ConflictGraph(dcel, verticesForCG);
  conflictGraph->initializeConflictGraph();

  //Loop through remaining vertices
  finalizeConvexHull(allVertices);
}

{
  facesVisible = conflictGraph->lookForVisibleFaces(remainingVertices[i]);
}
```

But in `ConvexHullBuilder.h` I get:

> `ConflictGraph` does not name a type

I tried taking a look to other answers on SO but I was not able to solve my issue with them.

**What causes this error? How can I prevent this? How can I use different external class methods on inner class different methods?**

Comment: So much code. Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: Much code? I put only the core piece of codes. Most of lines are comments that try to explain the purpose of the algorithm. If you think they are useless it's another thing.

Comment: There is no way you need four files to reproduce this problem. Part of debugging is _minimizing_ your code. Read the "[MCVE]" page please I didn't just link it for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue. It was caused by same `includes` in both classes. I needed to `include` a certain `module` only on the `header` of the class `included`. For instance, I had to do the includes only on `ConflictGraph.h` and not also in `ConvexHullBuilder`.

Here's how I'm able to access `ConflictGraph`'s different methods from inside `ConvexHullBuilder` functions

**ConvexHullBuilder.h**:

```
private:
   . . .
   ConflictGraph *conflictGraph;
```

**ConvexHullBuilder.cpp**:

```
void ConvexHullBuilder::computeConvexHull(){

  conflictGraph = new ConflictGraph(dcel, params);

  conflictGraph->initializeConflictGraph();
  finalizeConvexHull(parameters);

}

void ConvexHullBuilder::finalizeConvexHull(myType parameters){

  conflictGraph->lookForVisibleFaces(someParams);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will leak memory, as every time that `computeConvexHull` is called, you reallocate memory for a `ConflictGraph` object, and throw away the pointer to the previously allocated `ConflictGraph`. You should initialise `conflictGraph` to `nullptr` (or `NULL` prior to C++11) in the `ConvexHullBuilder` constructor, then in `computeConvexHull`, check whether `conflictGraph == nullptr` and if not, then either delete it prior to calling `new`, or just reuse the existing object. Then if `conflictGraph` is non-NULL during `ConvexHullBuilder` destruction, delete it then.

Comment: Thank you @DavidScarlett, I need to check how to release memory indeed. I'm literally programming in C++ from 5 days maybe.

Comment: In that case, consider structuring the class to avoid the need for using the new operator, which carries the danger of memory leaks. Consider how long the ConflictGraph object needs to exist for. Is it needed for the whole life of the ConvexHullBuilder object, or only during the computeConvexHull method call? This will dictate whether it should be a class member or locally declared and passed around as a function parameter. But if made a class member it must be initialised in the constructor, and if `dcel` and `params` are not available then, does ConflictGraph have a method to set them later?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `cinflictGraph` inside `finalizeConvexHull`. However, it was decleared in `computeConvexHull`. Member functions do not share local resource between each other.

**Solution:**

One possible solution without making a deep thought into your system is to declare  `conflictGraph` as private member variable of the class `ConvexHullBuilder`. So, you can use it in both member functions.

Comment: I'll edit my question. I tried your solution and get: `conflictGraph is not a type`.

Comment: Added that particular solution.

Comment: @AndreaM16 you do not need the "*" in the declreation

Comment: I'm forced to do so to access it. Project specifications.

Comment: Ok then at least use some smart pointer and initialize it in the constructor. and when you want to use it, use -> instead of .

Answer (score 1):

`conflictGraph` is declared in method `ConvexHullBuilder::computeConvexHull()` as a local variable, so it only exists while that function is being called. and is only accessible within that function. `finalizeConvexHull` is called by `computeConvexHull`, so `conflictGraph` does at least exist at the time of the call, but in order for `finalizeConvexHull` to be able to access it you would need to pass it as a parameter to that function.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a variable is always the block it is inside.

you need to declare your `conflictGraph` in the second function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare

```
private:
ConflictGraph conflictGraph;
```

in "ConvexHullBuilder.h" file

And declare in "ConvexHullBuilder.cpp" file as:

```
ConvexHullBuilder::ConvexHullBuilder(DrawableDcel* dcel){
   this->dcel = dcel;
   conflictGraph = ConflictGraph(dcel, verticesForCG);
}
```

Then you can use conflictGraph object in any function inside "ConvexHullBuilder.cpp" file

Comment: The problem is that I need to do that initialization after `verticesForCG` is set through several algorithms. So I don't know its value on the constructor. If I do so, I get: `verticesForCG` was not declared in this scope.

Comment: So you can declare "conflictGraph = ConflictGraph(dcel, verticesForCG);" once you have initialized the verticesForCG array. I should work then.

Comment: I do that but I get that error. I guess I need to access `ConflictGraph`'s methods inside `ConvexHullBuilder`'s method where I initialize it or always reinitialize it inside each method. Thanks anyways.